# Detect when item is changed in Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I would like to update the content of my Outlook Web Add-in when Calendar event data is changed. Is there any possibility to catch kind of `ItemChanged` event in the web add-ins?

<sup>I have found some projects with `OnSend`, but trying that way does not work, and there is only that event possible to catch.</sup>

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario in more detail? How is event data changed in your scenario, who is changing it? Are you talking about a case where you are the organizer of the event or an attendee?

Comment: I am displaying some contents of Outlook Calendar Appointment (dates, title, description) in my add-in. I want to reload the data (or inform the user) whenever appointment data are changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature you are specifying is not a part of the product. However, we are actively investigating what types of events would be beneficial for the platform.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there.
Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Comment: I'm trying to develop add-ins for some time and I need to tell you that only a few things works there! Documentation is misleading and a lot of things described there does not work in real cases. You should fix that issues to make it work.

Comment: We are always looking to improve our documentation, or fix bugs in our apis. Let us know which specific areas could be improved. However, new feature requests should go to user voice.

Comment: @ Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT Is there any update regarding this? I also tried to update the content of my Outlook Add-in when Calendar event data is changed. But didn't find a solution to detect data change.