# Officejs addin compose mode propertychange

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I am able to show add-in for compose mode, is it possible to get updates as user enters To, Cc's fields & others.

I am using the following code to get To field but it is not getting fired on changes

```
Office.cast.item.toMessageCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).to.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {

    if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {

      console.log(asyncResult.value);
    }
  });
```

I am trying to implement something like "Salesforce Lightning for Outlook" addin which already has this functionality.

If officeJS doesn't support this yet, is there a way to makeEWSRequest and watch for changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when item is changed in Outlook Web Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208246/detect-when-item-is-changed-in-outlook-web-add-in)

Comment: Salesforce Lightning for Outlook addin already has this functionality. I thought the getAsync would fire on any change to field but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OfficeJS currently doesn't have this functionality but for now the solution is to call getAsync on any field you need in a loop with interval and compare with previous values

```
setInterval(function () {
   Office.cast.item.toMessageCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item).to.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {

    if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {

     //compare with previous value

    }
  });
}, 2000); // Executes and looks for changes every 2 seconds.
```